# Application design UI Android Wear

Tags: android, wearables

I'm currently developing an application on Android Wear to have quick overview of the people attending to a party.

My problem is how to arrange the views to have the more efficient navigation.

Here you can see the actual views of the application. The card x.x are shown when a user clicks on a button a the card x.5.

Swipe is used to navigate between cards.

[image: Navigation]

According to the Android design principles, only five cards must be shown vertically so the first three attendees would be cards and after a list is shown.

This navigation is it correct ? How could it be improved ?

Comment: Why not stick to a List itself? Use a single card to notify about the Attendees and on opening it, have a list of attendees available, instead of swiping through each card and then making a sudden shift into a list. Maintains the flow.

Comment: I would also be tempted to flip the axes so that you sideswipe through the list of attendees and then vertical swipe through their details - that way you have the controlled number of cards on the vertical axis (Attendee details) and the uncontrolled number of cards (all attendees) on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 1):

We use the 5 or 6 count rule in our wearable platforms too. It's a very good rule of thumb.  Stress levels go up if you have to deal with more items at one time.  If you need longer list then the wrist is probably the wrong place for the feature.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Also, m *can be* greater than 5 (but not a ridiculously large number).

Five cards is a suggestion, not a set rule!
(From the Android docs.. "and limit the the vertical set to *about* five cards.")
The suggestion has obviously been made to focus on one of the fundamental requirements of wearables - brevity!